# source control with VB2005 Express

Tags: vb.net, version-control

Can anyone suggest a good source control system that interfaces with VB2005 Express? As the Express editions of Visual Studio do not allow add-ins does this mean that I will not be able to integrate source control into the IDE? I'm used to the check-in/check-out process of SourceSafe integrated into VB6. Can anyone recommend TortoiseSVN as an alternative?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, i dislike VSS with a passion. I just can't get my head around doing source control in Windows explorer! I'll install TortoiseSQN and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is a good choice.  Although it won't integrate into the IDE (because of the plug-in problem you mentioned), it's really solid in the Explorer right-button menu.

Also consider [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) from SourceGear.  If you're used to SourceSafe, Vault will be easier to learn; Vault was specifically designed for ex-SourceSafe users.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com). It is lightning fast, rock solid, simple to use and configure, and has features to support pretty much any source control scenario.

If you are working on your own (which seems likely, given that you are using VB 2k5 Express), it is free for up to two users. If / when you switch to VS Pro, it has very good integration, and on its own it has several excellent clients and Windows Explorer integration.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Tortoise and do version control through Windows Explorer.

I actually prefer that to Ankh in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

I use TortoiseSVN and windows explorer for all my development projects and believe it works great.  I started with SourceSafe, but when I changed jobs I went to an SVN shop and have now incorporated it into my own development projects.  You can also use Source Safe without integration.  You use Source Safe to check in/out files in a folder and then manage it outside the IDE.  While this isn't as "simple" it may work just fine for certain projects.  I use a hosted SVN provider, you may want to check them out: [Hosted-Projects](http://www.hosted-projects.com/).

Answer (score 0):

No, Source Control systems can't be integrated with the VS Express IDEs by design.

If you want to continue using your existing VSS, you're best option is to upgrade to Visual Studio Standard.  Otherwise, check out TortoiseSVN.  Here's a good quick start:

http://www.polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/subversion/

Comment: Less by design, and more by force. Microsoft explicitly forbids add-in for express, even though it is actually technically possible to make them.